# How to get the step-by-step derivative of this?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I'm very newbie to Mathematica, and wanted to use it to help me solve some questions that I don't have the math backing to help me solve on paper. I would like to take this equation and have it be a partial derivative. However, I would also like a step-by-step to help hand hold me the way through so I know what is going on. Instead, what I get is this error message. Could someone please help?

```
WolframAlpha["D[-T0/ ProductLog[-E^(-1+dS/dC), dS]"]
```

`WolframAlpha::timeout: The call to WolframAlpha[D[-T0/ ProductLog[-E^(-1+dS/dC), dS]] has exceeded 30. seconds. Increasing the value of the TimeConstraint option may improve the result.`

Thank you!

Comment: There might be an issue parsing this query. If we simplify a bit, we get steps: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=D%5B1%2FProductLog%5B-E%5E%28-1%2Bx%29%5D%2C+x%5D

Comment: Thank you, I think this helps!